# Mathematical (exp) function result vs glibc version

Tags: c++, linux, glibc, ieee-754, libm

I need your help regarding an explanation (and maybe a workaround) regarding different results produced by `exp()` mathematical function on some Linux distros.

Results are produced by this very simple program :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  double a = -9.55258983280695383e-03;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits< double >::max_digits10) << std::scientific ;
  std::cout << exp(a) << ";" <<  expf(a) << ";" << expl(a) << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, `double`, `float` and `long double` version of `exp()` function are tested.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 exp.cxx
$ ./a.out
```

Results by distros :

|  | exp(a) | expf(a) | expl(a) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stretch | 9.90492891217632399e-01 | 9.90492880344390869e-01 | 9.90492891217632453e-01 |
| buster | **9.90492891217632510e-01** | 9.90492880344390869e-01 | 9.90492891217632453e-01 |
| bullseye | 9.90492891217632399e-01 | 9.90492880344390869e-01 | 9.90492891217632453e-01 |
| bookworm | 9.90492891217632399e-01 | 9.90492880344390869e-01 | 9.90492891217632453e-01 |
| xenial | 9.90492891217632399e-01 | 9.90492880344390869e-01 | 9.90492891217632453e-01 |
| focal | 9.90492891217632399e-01 | 9.90492880344390869e-01 | 9.90492891217632453e-01 |
| jammy | 9.90492891217632399e-01 | 9.90492880344390869e-01 | 9.90492891217632453e-01 |
| Maipo | 9.90492891217632399e-01 | 9.90492880344390869e-01 | 9.90492891217632453e-01 |
| Ootpa | **9.90492891217632510e-01** | 9.90492880344390869e-01 | 9.90492891217632453e-01 |

Why do buster (debian 10) and Ootpa (RedHat 8) return (the same) different value ?

Where to search for an explanation ?

I noticed that glibc versions are the same (2.28) for buster and Ootpa and that any other version returns the expected result :

|  | g++ | glibc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| stretch | 6.3.0 | 2.24 |
| buster | 8.3.0 | **2.28** |
| bullseye | 10.2.1 | 2.31 |
| bookworm | 11.3.0 | 2.33 |
| xenial | 5.4.0 | 2.23 |
| focal | 9.4.0 | 2.31 |
| jammy | 11.2.0 | 2.35 |
| Maipo | 4.8.5 | 2.17 |
| Ootpa | 8.5.0 | **2.28** |

Any suggestion ?

Comment: You might want to add a test that prints out `a` on the various platforms.  There have been issues in the `strtod` function which would impact the input to the tests.

Comment: The two different values  are 'adjacent' representations for an IEEE-754 `double`; that is, their representations are 1 bit different. May the actual value is between them, in which case there may be a different default rounding mode in use. But is it even a concern when they are such adjacent values?

Comment: You cannot rely on floating point results being exactly reproducible. Even different CPU:s will make the results differ unless you use specific standards such as SSE.

Comment: @SvenNilsson if the implementation claims to conform to IEEE-754, it *should* produce the same result for `std::exp` on all CPUs. Poor reproducibility usually only happens when you're doing `-ffast-math` or using SSE/NEON intrinsics, which explicitly are *not* IEEE-754 conformant. (_Representability_ is a different issue, which may cause things like _0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3_.)

Comment: It’s probably the environment. If you’re compiling for AMD64, use `_mm_getcsr` to get that piece of the environment. See that article for the documentation of various fields packed into the 32-bit value: https://help.totalview.io/previous_releases/2019/html/index.html#page/Reference_Guide/Intelx86MXSCRRegister.html

Comment: @RichardCritten, i simplified the example, but i did verify that `a` is printed exactly as entered on all distros. thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes, they are adjacent values. But how to explain the different behavior, where could it had been set ? It's a concern when you have to identity and explain differences in numerical computation with tons of mathematical operations that tends to amplify differences (fixed point resolution).

Comment: Here's the precise value accurate to displayed precision: 0.99049289121763245327082425794342331879543338283171

Comment: @You: “if the implementation claims to conform to IEEE-754”: Do you know any implementation that claims to conform to IEEE-754? Can you show us the statement making that claim?

Comment: The transcendental math functions in the standard C and C++ libraries are generally not implemented with “correct rounding” as defined by the IEEE-754 standard. They are complicated routines, and, to my knowledge, nobody has yet fully implemented them with proven known bounds on the execution times. The routines are generally implemented using polynomial approximations and other techniques that produce very accurate results but may differ by a few ULP from the ideal results (sometimes more in low-quality implementations)…

Comment: … Different implementors use different polynomial approximations, as well as having other differences in the routine (such as how argument reductions are done and how the extended-precision arithmetic is done), and, at times, the implementations may be changed to suit new hardware or other purposes. These differences result in differences in the results.

Comment: Also note that while the IEEE-754 2008 standard recommends that floating-point implementations provide various routines, including `exp`, that are correctly rounded, this is not a requirement. Additionally, the IEEE-754 committee did not approve this wording. The final committee draft allowed a more relaxed accuracy, reflecting the fact that humans had not yet produced implementations of the routines with the desired practice, but it was changed in the IEEE balloting process.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for this enlightment regarding how math functions are not strictly included in IEEE-754 standardization and the rounding correctness. What I would like to understand is, why, in the context of only one "vendor" (GNU), such differences appear for only one version (2.28), not before, not after.